# How to approach to develop a multi target mobile web application

Tags: iphone, asp.net, android, mobile

i'm newbie to mobile devices, and i've to develop a simple database driven application targeted for mobile devices, in asp.net .
In particular, my customer needed to:

> 1. Access with their account to our database
> 2. Make Photos to some items
> 3. Associate to it some datas: price, some date, ...
> 4. Publish it

I thought i can build a "single" web app maybe with jquerymobile, instead one app for device . 
So customers can access to web app via browser and a standard www.something.com .

Could this approach be good ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web apps don't have access to camera. In your case you might want to go native or use something like phonegap or appcelerator.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that would work. Not sure what the question is beyond that?

Comment: I don't know what's the best approach: if i've to develop  a native application, or maybe a web application with jquerymobile is enough for a simple application like the one's i've described before..

Comment: Whether to develop a native application or a web-based one is a much bigger question. Some functionality is only available to native apps, but some things are blocked from apps (because of the approval process). Speed is another issue - native apps will always be faster. Your knowledge of Objective C and HTML/JavaScript is important. There are so many factors involved, it's difficult to give you an answer about the 'best' way of doing this.